# Google Sign in : 404 error thrown during gapi.load

Tags: google-api-js-client, google-signin

I integrated google sign in into our website using listeners using this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners) from the official Docs.

It was working perfectly fine until recently.

```
gapi.load('auth2', () => { // Error occurs here
  auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: 'MY CLIENT ID',
    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
  });
// Other code here
});
```

During the initial gapi.load, I get a 404 error.
Attached a screenshot of it here from the chrome inspector tools.

[image]

I have pasted the error here directly.

```
Request URL:https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.kouJO3hwSnU.O/m=auth2/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=AQ/rs=
AGLTcCOEP7w5Py-EdoYJe54gagnXDmyBmg/cb=gapi.loaded_0
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:172.217.26.206:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
content-length:0
content-type:text/html
date:Wed, 11 Oct 2017 10:36:28 GMT
server:sffe
status:404
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your image link has an issue, mate. Please edit/fix.

Comment: Yeah, added the error message to the question here directly. Check it out now.